# What is the expected number of times you need to flip a coin before you see 2 heads? The heads do not need to be in a row

Tags: probability, self-study, expected-value

My attempt:

The 2nd head must appear last in the sequence of k flips. Therefore the first head can appear in any of the first k-1 flips. The number of ways the first head appearing in the first k-1 flips is ${k-1\choose 1} = (k-1)$. Each sequence has a $ p^{k-1} $ chance of appearing

$$P(X=k)=(k-1)p^{k-1}p = (k-1)p^k = (k-1)(.5)^k$$

Now when I try to calculate the expected value:

$E(X) = \sum\limits_{x = 1}^{\infty}x(x-1)(.5)^x\ $.

After entering some large values of x, it seems $E(X) = 4$

Is this correct?

Comment: If you are at all interested in probability, it would be a good idea to get some practice in summing series like the one for $E[X]$ that you have shown, and yes, it can be _proved_ that your sum for $E[X]$ does have value $4$ without resorting to "entering large values of $x$" whatever that means.

Comment: Have a look at this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/102683/620244

Comment: Hint: how long should it take to see the first head?

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is correct, but your derivation does not quite get there.  Suppose we let $K_1$ be the number of flips until the first head, $K_2$ be the number of *additional* flips until the next head, and so on.  Then we have $K_1,K_2,K_3,... \sim \text{IID Geom}(p)$ and so the number of flips until the $n$th head is:

$$S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n K_i \sim \text{NegBin}(n,p).$$

The full distribution of this quantity can be found easily enough, but the expectation is even simpler:

$$\mathbb{E}(S_n) = \mathbb{E} \bigg(  \sum_{i=1}^n K_i \bigg) =  \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}(K_i) =  \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{p} = \frac{n}{p}.$$

In your case you have assumed that $p = 1/2$ and you want to find the expected number of flips until the second head, which is $\mathbb{E}(S_2) = 2 / p = 4.$